# How to determine if SelectedIndexChanged is firing because of de-selection or selection

Tags: c#, listview, windows-forms-designer

I am using the SelectedIndexChanged on my listView- depending on the selection, some buttons will be enabled or disabled. My issue is that SelectedIndexChanged is being called twice, once for the de-selection of one index and another time for the selection of another.This is causing a flicker in the forecolor of my button. Without using a global boolean, how can I check for the event firing due to de-selection?

```
private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//This is meant to disable all buttons when no items/indexes are selected
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        BtnActivate.Enabled = false;
        BtnLicManually.Enabled = false;
        BtnDeactivate.Enabled = false;
        BtnTransfer.Enabled = false;
        return;
    }
//There is more code here to determine which buttons are disabled or enabled based on user index selection and other variables personal to their machine.
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the paint event. Please show your code.

Comment: It would be much better if you moved some of the text to the next line

Comment: Are you doing something to trigger the paint event?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I edited my post to remove the part about the paint event because after removing it and using the standard forecolor for the disabled button, the flicker is still happening! I assume at this point it has everything to do with the SelectedIndexChanged event being called twice :/

Answer (score 1):

Try ItemSelectionChanged instead of SelectedIndexChanged.
Its ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs contains all necessary information.

- bool IsSelected
- ListViewItem Item
- int ItemIndex

(Tested with Visual Studio 2019, .NET Framework 4.7.2)

My suggestion for a (cleaner) approach would be to create a custom button, maybe override the OnPaint and the OnEnabledChanged method. Setting DoubleBuffered = true helps too sometimes.

Comment: After removing the paint event and using the standard forecolor for the disabled button, the flicker is still happening. I assume it has to do with the selectedIndexChanged being fired twice. Unfortunately ItemSelectedChanged does not work for us in this case, it was one of the first workarounds we tried. I may try adding a custom button though, Thank you!

Comment: After recreating your problem I understand why ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs doesn't help you either. I still think a custom button would be nice, but I doubt it would help with the flickering. Two rather crude options: A) use a timer (or DataFlow/TPL Blocks) B) use mouse up/down events. nothing really nice. perhaps override listview or use something different than the listview in the first place. Sorry I couldn't provide you a better answer.

Comment: Replacing ItemSelectionChanged event with the MouseUp event worked in my tests. Needs proper testing though.

Comment: You added a MouseUp event to the listView?

Comment: Yes, I just used MouseUp instead of SelectedIndexChanged. Assuming that the ListView is only used with mouse commands, this event is fired after all de- selections happened. After that you can inspect which listviewitems are selected and change your buttons accordingly. You still have to test wether the user can change selection without firing the MouseUp event.

Comment: I'm not sure how it happened but the flicker is gone today. Fixed a different bug that had to do with licensing and the flicker disappeared. I appreciate your help though, thank you!